# ¿Cómo rellenar un DropDown desde Excel en PowerApps?

Tags: dropdownlist, powerapps

Estoy introduciendome en PowerApps y necesito llenar un Drop Down List con una lista excel de la cual solo he de recoger los que coincidan con una key, pero el DropDown se rellena vacío. El fichero de String simplemente contiene un texto para cada key. He intentando hacer lo siguiente:

```
[Filter(Strings.Key; Key = "btnAceptar" && "btnCancelar")]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el resultado. He probado diversas formulas con Choices y LookUp, pero todas me muestran errores ambiguos. ¿Alguna pista de como podría hacer esto que quiero?.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

pasalo a una coleccion primero.

clearcollect(exceloff;excel)

el choice y lookup son para etiquetas, para campos masivo usaria el filter con un distinc para borrar los duplicados y espacios en blancos

Distinct(filter(basedatos;columna filtro;columna resultado)